# Creating new column based on earliest date value in other column in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame which looks like:

```
Subject = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
OBS = c(1.3,2.4,3.3,4.2,1.2,2.7,3.6,4.9)
REFDATE = as.Date(c('2013-09-25', '2013-09-25', '2013-09-26', '2013-09-26', '2013-09-27', '2013-    09-27', '2013-09-30', '2013-09-30')) 
df1 = data.frame(Subject, OBS, REFDATE)
```

I want to add a new column (REFDATE2) which only contains the earliest REFDATE for *each* Subject, yielding this:

```
Subject = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
OBS = c(1.3,2.4,3.3,4.2,1.2,2.7,3.6,4.9)
REFDATE = as.Date(c('2013-09-25', '2013-09-25', '2013-09-26', '2013-09-26', '2013-09-27', '2013-    09-27', '2013-09-30', '2013-09-30'))
REFDATE2 = as.Date(c('2013-09-25', '2013-09-25', '2013-09-25', '2013-09-25', '2013-09-27', '2013-    09-27', '2013-09-27', '2013-09-27')) 
df2 = data.frame(Subject, OBS, REFDATE, REFDATE2)
```

There is quite a large number of subjects in the dataset. I suspect some kind of loop function which can identify the earliest date would do the trick?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Sincerily,

ykl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or using `data.table` package (which is also easy and fast)

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- as.data.frame(data.table(df1)[, REFDATE2:= min(REFDATE), by = Subject])
df1

# Subject OBS    REFDATE   REFDATE2
# 1       1 1.3 2013-09-25 2013-09-25
# 2       1 2.4 2013-09-25 2013-09-25
# 3       1 3.3 2013-09-26 2013-09-25
# 4       1 4.2 2013-09-26 2013-09-25
# 5       2 1.2 2013-09-27 2013-09-27
# 6       2 2.7 2013-09-27 2013-09-27
# 7       2 3.6 2013-09-30 2013-09-27
# 8       2 4.9 2013-09-30 2013-09-27
```

## Edit

Per OPs request, if you want to add time, instead of `as.Date` do `as.POSIXct`, something like:

```
Subject = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
OBS = c(1.3,2.4,3.3,4.2,1.2,2.7,3.6,4.9)
REFDATE = as.POSIXct(c('2013-09-25 08:30:00', '2013-09-25 08:30:00', '2013-09-26 08:30:00', '2013-09-26 08:30:00', '2013-09-27 08:30:00', '2013-09-27 08:30:00', '2013-09-30 08:30:00', '2013-09-30 08:30:00')) 
df1 = data.frame(Subject, OBS, REFDATE)

library(data.table)
df1 <- as.data.frame(data.table(df1)[, REFDATE2:= min(REFDATE), by = Subject])
df1

# Subject OBS             REFDATE            REFDATE2
# 1       1 1.3 2013-09-25 08:30:00 2013-09-25 08:30:00
# 2       1 2.4 2013-09-25 08:30:00 2013-09-25 08:30:00
# 3       1 3.3 2013-09-26 08:30:00 2013-09-25 08:30:00
# 4       1 4.2 2013-09-26 08:30:00 2013-09-25 08:30:00
# 5       2 1.2 2013-09-27 08:30:00 2013-09-27 08:30:00
# 6       2 2.7 2013-09-27 08:30:00 2013-09-27 08:30:00
# 7       2 3.6 2013-09-30 08:30:00 2013-09-27 08:30:00
# 8       2 4.9 2013-09-30 08:30:00 2013-09-27 08:30:00
```

Comment: Sorry to add more questions, but how do I use this when I also have the time in my REFDATE column (e.g. 2013-09-25 08:30:00) ? I get an 'error Type 25 in .SD column 0' when I try.

Comment: See edit above, basically you need to use `as.POSIXct` instead of `as.Date`

Comment: Why convert back to `data.frame`? Also you can use `setDT` to convert `data.frame` to `data.table` by reference.

Comment: @Arun, I've converted back to `data.frame` because I suspected that the OP wanted a dataframe result as he is not familiar with `data.table` package and could get confused by it's different syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy (and fast) using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %.% group_by(Subject) %.% mutate(REFDATE2=min(REFDATE))
```

Which gives :

```
Source: local data frame [8 x 4]
Groups: Subject

  Subject OBS    REFDATE   REFDATE2
1       1 1.3 2013-09-25 2013-09-25
2       1 2.4 2013-09-25 2013-09-25
3       1 3.3 2013-09-26 2013-09-25
4       1 4.2 2013-09-26 2013-09-25
5       2 1.2 2013-09-27 2013-09-27
6       2 2.7 2013-09-27 2013-09-27
7       2 3.6 2013-09-30 2013-09-27
8       2 4.9 2013-09-30 2013-09-27
```