# R Creating vector based on earliest date from another column receive POSIX error

Tags: r, date

I am referencing another post that appears to provide the exact solution I'm looking for:

[Creating new column based on earliest date value in other column in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23214761/creating-new-column-based-on-earliest-date-value-in-other-column-in-r)

Here is my sample data:

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a1", "b1"), class = "factor"), Begin = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hour = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mday = c(28L, 4L, 10L, 10L, 12L, 13L), mon = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L), year = c(115L, 115L,115L, 115L, 115L, 115L), wday = c(1L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 0L), yday = c(361L, 337L, 343L, 343L, 345L, 346L), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), zone = c("PST", "PST", "PST", "PST", "PST", "PST"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", "zone", "gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"))), .Names = c("ID", "Begin"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is what I am looking for:

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a1", "b1"), class = "factor"), Begin = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), hour = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mday = c(28L, 4L, 10L, 10L, 12L, 13L), mon = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L), year = c(115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L), wday = c(1L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 0L), yday = c(361L, 337L, 343L, 343L, 345L, 346L), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), zone = c("PST", "PST", "PST", "PST", "PST", "PST"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", "zone", "gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")), BeginE = structure(list(
sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), hour = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mday = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 
10L, 10L, 10L), mon = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L), year = c(115L, 
115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L), wday = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
4L), yday = c(337L, 337L, 337L, 343L, 343L, 343L), isdst = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), zone = c("PST", "PST", "PST", "PST", 
"PST", "PST"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", "zone", "gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"))), .Names = c("ID", "Begin", "BeginE"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

In response to good comment about providing all code, I attempted the following:

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(data.table(df)[, BeginE:= min(Begin), by = ID])
```

This was the error:

```
`Error in as.POSIXct.POSIXlt(X[[i]], ...) : invalid 'x' argument`
```

Comment: `df$BeginE <- ave(df$Begin, df$ID, FUN = min)`

Comment: It's best to include all the relevant code (and data) into your post.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue with a simple conversion:

```
df$Begin<-as.POSIXct(df$Begin)
```

Works on my huge dataset as well.